# Understanding list comprehensions in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, list-comprehension

When reading the [official tutorial](https://docs.python.org/2.7/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions), I encountered this example:

```
>>> vec = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]]

>>> [num for elem in vec for num in elem]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

I couldn't understand this, so I did some experiments:

```
>>> [num for elem in vec]
[9, 9, 9]

>>> [num for elem in (vec for num in elem)]
[9, 9, 9]
```

And I'm even more confused now!

In which order should I read a list comprehension?

---

I'm sure I haven't defined a `num` variable with the value 9 anywhere.

```
python
```

Output:

```
Python 2.7.10 (default, Oct 23 2015, 19:19:21)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 7.0.0 (clang-700.0.59.5)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
```

[REPL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read-eval-print_loop) session:

```
>>> num
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'num' is not defined

>>> vec = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]]

>>> [num for elem in vec for num in elem]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

>>> [num for elem in vec]
[9, 9, 9]

>>> [num for elem in (vec for num in elem)]
[9, 9, 9]
```

Comment: I'm confused too. `[num for elem in vec]` should throw an error because `num` is not defined. Are you sure you haven't defined a `num` variable with the value `9` somewhere?

Comment: @Rawing Yes, I'm sure. See my updated question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The loops in list comprehension are read from left to right. If your list comprehension would be written as an ordinary loop, it would look something like this:

```
>>> vec = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]]
>>> l = []
>>> for elem in vec:
...     for num in elem:
...         l.append(num)
...
>>> l

[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

In Python 2, the variables within the list comprehension share the outer scope, so `num` is available to be used later:

```
>>> vec = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]]

>>> [num for elem in vec for num in elem]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

>>> num
9
```

Note that on Python 3, the behavior is different:

```
>>> vec = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]]

>>> [num for elem in vec for num in elem]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

>>> num
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'num' is not defined
```

Answer (score 2):

When you execute the list comprehension, the value of `num` is `9`, so the next time you iterate through the `vec` you will get a list of `9`.

See this.

```
In [1]: vec = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]]

In [2]: [num for elem in vec for num in elem]
Out[2]: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

In [3]: num
Out[3]: 9

In [4]: [num for elem in vec]
Out[4]: [9, 9, 9]
```

Comment: @sunqingyao No, it's not a bug that list comprehensions in older versions of Python run in the scope of the surrounding code. It was intentionally done like that for reasons of efficiency. But so many complained about it that it was changed for Python 3. Which means that Python 3 list comps don't "leak", but they are also a little slower than Python 2 list comps, and consume a little more RAM.

Answer (score 0):

Let me try to make the answer more clear. And the order obviously will be from left to right and most right value will be stored in the variable, i.e., *num* and *elem*.

Initial data:

```
vec = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]]
num  # Undefined
elem # Undefined
```

Step 1: After execution of line `[num for elem in vec for num in elem]`

```
# Now the value of undefined variable will be
num = 9  # Will keep the last value of the loop as per Python 2.7
elem = [7, 8, 9]   # The same applies here (as the loop
                   # for 'elem' in 'vec' will get
                   # executed first, followed by
                   # for 'num' in 'elem')
```

Step 2: After execution of line `[num for elem in vec]`

```
# Output: [9, 9, 9]
# Since num value is 9 and its get repeated 3 times because of
# 'vec' has three elements (three list object in a list, so
# the 'for' loop will run three times)
# Now the variable value would be
num = 9 # No change
elem = [7, 8, 9] # The last tuple of variable vec
```

Step 3: After the execution of `[num for elem in (vec for num in elem)]`

1. In the first/right loop, i.e., (*vec* for *num* in *elem*)

   Here the result will be a generator that will have run thrice since the length of *elem* is 3.
2. The final *for* loop will iterate over RESULT1 (the result of *for* loop #1 having length 3) and since the *num* value is 9. The result will be [9, 9, 9] # 'num' value repeated thrice.

Comment: What do you mean *"most right value"*? *"[rightmost](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/rightmost#Adjective) value"*? Or something else?

Comment: Yes, it rightmost value

Answer (score -1):

```
list1 = [num for elem in vec for num in elem]
```

is equivalent to:

```
list1 = []
for elem in vec:
    for num in elem:
       list1.append(num)
```

Comment: Actually OP have problem with the next lines. Not this one.