# Why does calling n^2 for numbers in a range produce the results out of order?

Tags: python

```
>>> nums = {n**2 for n in range(10)}
>>> nums
{0, 1, 64, 4, 36, 9, 16, 49, 81, 25}
```

I dont get why the numbers are out of order? Should it not be {0, 1, 4, 9...}?

Comment: Because [sets](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html) are by definition *unordered collections of unique elements*.

Comment: it is on  some implementation (python 3.6.1,Windows)  : In [4]: {n**2 for n in range(10)}
-> Out[4]: {0, 1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81}

Comment: @B.M. sets never guarantee to retain insertion ordered on any python implementation

Comment: @C_R I never say that ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because you have created a set, and sets are unordered. If you wanted order, you should use a standard list comprehension:

```
>>> nums = [n**2 for n in range(10)]
>>> nums
[0, 1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81]
```

Comment: What determines what order it is? Another computer gave the same output so surely its not a random order.

Comment: @AlonzoRobbe its the same as `num = []; for n in range(10): num.append(n**2)` just as list comp. See [Understanding list comps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38408991/understanding-list-comprehensions-in-python) - they are appended in order of creation - and lists are stable.

Comment: @AlonzoRobbe Items are stored in sets by their hash (which in the main CPython implementation is the number itself for small ints) but sets are dynamically resized as you add to them and Python does not reorder a set when it is resized. You should never count on any specific ordering in a set.

Answer (score 4):

You're just using a `set`. A `set` is an *unordered* data structure.

One approach could be using `sorted` method.

```
sorted_lst = sorted(nums)
```

Output

```
[0, 1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81]
```